# how to combine two columns in from two t-sql select?

Tags: t-sql

I'm using t-sql. 
I want to return a dataTable with two coulmns: A,B

But the 'union' is not the way. What syntax should I use?

```
select Params as A
from Table1
where ID = '1'

union

select Params as B
from Table1
where ID = '2'
```

**update: So sorry, I had a typo: @CITD => ID**

TIA

Comment: Please add some example data and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: It'll be a JOIN but you'll need to show a source example and the result you want. Specifying A, B is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select T1.Params as A, T2.Params as B
from Table1 T1 
INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON  @CTID = '1' AND @ID = '2'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how `A` and `B` relate its impossible to create a logical result set where neither `A` or `B` equal `NULL` for one record.

The following will give you 1 result set with 2 columns, but will need more info on how they relate if you wish for them to be 'merged' more:

```
select Params as A, NULL as B
from Table1
where @CTID = '1'

union

select NULL as A, Params as B
from Table1
where @ID = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE ID WHEN '1' THEN Params END) AS A,
  MAX(CASE ID WHEN '2' THEN Params END) AS B
FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN ('1', '2')
```